# The meaning of "that is neither here nor there."

Tags: meaning

And Paul said to me: “Serve Caesar. You are not canvas I can cut to advantage at present. But if you serve Caesar you will be obeying at least some sort of law.”

> He talked as though I were a barbarian. Weak as I was, I could have
>   snapped his back with my bare hands. I told him so. “I don’t doubt
>   it,” he said. **“But that is neither here nor there.** If you take
>   refuge under Caesar at sea, you may have time to think. Then I may
>   meet you again, and we can go on with our talks. But that is as The
>   God wills. What concerns you now is that, by taking service, you will
>   be free from the fear that has ridden you all your life.”’

This is from "The Manner of Men" by Rudyard Kipling.
https://www.telelib.com/authors/K/KiplingRudyard/prose/LimitsRenewals/mannermen.html

I do not understand the meaning of
But that is neither here nor there.

What did Paul intend to say by that?

I am glad if some one would  kindly teach me.

Comment: Did you look in a dictionary? It is [there](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neither_here_nor_there)

Answer (score 1):

"Neither here nor there" means "not important, or not connected with the subject being discussed".

[Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/neither-here-nor-there)